# While/For loop trouble

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

When I was looking at this code, I initially thought that it would be an infinite loop. But when I ran the code I got this as the output(attached as an image). I was wondering if someone could explain me why this output was given?

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    for (int j = i; j > 1; j--)
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    System.out.println("******");
    i++;
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be infinite?

Comment: Because I thought that the print statements and the increment statement are within the for loop.

Comment: That wouldn't make it infinite

Comment: To put multiple statements in a `for` loop, you need to put them in curly braces.  If the curly braces aren't there, then only the next statement is inside the `for` loop, and the statement after that is outside.  However, putting all three statements inside curly braces wouldn't make the loop infinite (try it).

Comment: O ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this is not an infinite loop because i is geting incremented

```
while (i < 5) {
    for (int j = i; j > 1; j--)
        System.out.print(j + " "); //only statement in the for
    System.out.println("******");
    i++;
}
```

as you see, the only statement in the for loop is the  `System.out.print(j + " ");` , you can expand more than one statement y wrapping them with **{}**